# Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type()) in opencv

Tags: opencv, transparent

I have a png image `pic.png` and I am making it transparent by using the below function `createMask()`

```
    origpic = cvLoadImage("/root/opencv/newtutorial/newcode_try2/pic.png",1);
    pic = createMask(origpic);
```

I have createMask function

```
    IplImage* createMask(IplImage* image) {
        IplImage *mask;
        mask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
        cvInRangeS(image, cvScalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), cvScalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), mask);
        cvNot(mask, mask);
        return mask;
    }
```

Now my problem is when I am warping it with

`cvWarpPerspective( pic, neg_img, warp_matrix);`

I am getting this error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type()) in cvWarpPerspective, 
file /root/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3234
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /root/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3234:
error: (-215) src.type() == dst.type() in function cvWarpPerspective
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the destination image with same type as pic. And the createMask() function creates a grayscale image.

so before calling warpPerspective, add this line:

```
neg_img = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pic),8,1);
```

Note that you may use a different size for your destination image, and the result will be cropped, or, depending on warp_matrix, filled with black space around:

```
neg_img = cvCreateImage(CvSize(200,300),8,1);
```

And also, a better idea would be to use the c++ interface, with Mat instead of IplImage. It automatically takes care of memory management, it is cleaner and easier to use. The only situation where you actually have to use c interface is some embedded systems, where the compiler is C only.

Comment: Sorry I am getting this error OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in binary_op, file /root/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp

Comment: That's because you try to check the range of a 1-channel image with a 3-channel Scalar interval. And I cannoy guess why you actually use that call there, the code will be the same without that line.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You must convert your image to grayscale (cvCvtColor()), and send the result to the checkrange. What you have there is a 3-channel image, checked for range, and the result you are trying to store in a 1-channel image. Error!

Comment: So what should I do bro. I really appreciate your help please help. I made this change `neg_img = cvCreateImage(CvSize(600,400),8,1);`

Comment: I am getting this now OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size && dst.type() == CV_8U) in cvInRangeS, file /root/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot do the work for you :) Please make sure what you want with that function (createMask), it seems nonsense to me, it checks if some uchars are between 0 and 255, or maybe just equal to 255, or maybe it's doing nothing. Make sure you know what you're doing there.

Comment: Can I paste the whole code ..Will you help me...+1 for your help

Comment: Sorry, but no. SO is not a chat room, and I am not a free debugger. use your own brain to understand the problem (You actually do not have any idea about that code, isn't it?)

Comment: Ya but I am trying to...Please help...I am near to get that